# CSS - issue with checkbox labels with html5

Tags: css, html

With the following HTML and CSS, the check box labels appear fine in IE8 and Firefox 25 when I use the Doctype to transitional (or loose dtd).  When I change the Doctype to html5, the check box labels appear fine in IE8, but in Firefox, each check box label is broken between "Checkbox" and the number.  What would I change so that the check box labels render correctly for both IE8 and Firefox?

```
<!-- Check box labels render fine in IE8 and Firefox -->
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">-->

<!-- Check box lables render fine in IE8 but not Firefox -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<style type="text/css">
body
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}

label.fieldLabel
{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right:10px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}

.reqField
{
    color: Red;
    padding: 0px 5px; 
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.notReqField
{
    padding: 0px 5px; 
    width: 5px;
    float: left;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<form id="checkboxForm" action="/webdesign/getCheckboxForm.do" method="POST">

                    <label class="fieldLabel">Checkbox (grouped):</label>
                    <span class="reqField">*</span>

                    <div id="checkboxGroup" style="vertical-align: bottom; overflow: auto; float: left;">
                        <span>
                            <input id="checkboxList1" name="checkboxList" tabindex="3" required="required" type="checkbox" value="Checkbox 1"/>
                            <label for="checkboxList1">Checkbox 1</label>
                        </span>
                        <span><br>
                            <input id="checkboxList2" name="checkboxList" tabindex="3" required="required" type="checkbox" value="Checkbox 2"/>
                            <label for="checkboxList2">Checkbox 2</label>
                        </span>
                        <span><br>
                            <input id="checkboxList3" name="checkboxList" tabindex="3" required="required" type="checkbox" value="Checkbox 3"/>
                            <label for="checkboxList3">Checkbox 3</label>
                        </span>
                        <span><br>
                            <input id="checkboxList4" name="checkboxList" tabindex="3" required="required" type="checkbox" value="Checkbox 4"/>
                            <label for="checkboxList4">Checkbox 4</label>
                        </span>
                        <input type="hidden" name="_checkboxList" value="on"/>
                    </div>

                    </form> 

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/qxt65

Comment: *each check box label is broken between "Checkbox" and the number* eh?

Comment: You may want to look into a CSS reset - like http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html

Comment: What do you mean with broken? Is the number on the next line?

Comment: @Liam yes, that's what's happening in FF.

Comment: @putvande Yes, the number is displayed on the next line.  Definitely not what I want when I use the html5 Doctype.

Comment: Seems ok: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/qxt65

Comment: @isherwood I can't get that jsfiddle to open in IE8.  Unfortunately, IE8 is the standard browser for the company I work for.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of your parent div `checkboxGroup`. Firefox tends to set a width on floating divs. Here this automatic width is too small to display labels beside checkboxes.

I'll edit my answer to add more details.

So, change

```
<div id="checkboxGroup" style="vertical-align: bottom; overflow: auto; float: left;">
```

To (set width)

```
<div id="checkboxGroup" style="vertical-align: bottom; overflow: auto; float: left; width: 200px;">
```

Or (remove float)

```
<div id="checkboxGroup" style="vertical-align: bottom; overflow: auto;">
```

Comment: This works for FF.  However, in IE8, the first checkbox appears to the left of the label, but the remaining three checkboxes now appear underneath the label.  Ugh!

Comment: Which solution did you choose ? Try to play with div width, or set `nowrap` attribute on your label elements.

Comment: I removed the float property.  Let me try the nowrap attribute on the labels.

Comment: Let me revise what I previously said.  In FF, everything's OK.  This is true whether I add nowrap to the labels or not.  In IE8, all of the checkboxes are lined up properly, but they all appear underneath my red required field indicator (*).

Comment: You can try to put the "red required field indicator (*)" into `checkboxGroup` div.

Comment: It seems that FF didn't like the SPAN tag that enclosed each checkbox.  I modified the code that was generated the checkboxes so that the extraneous SPAN tags were no longer generated, and things look fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of artificial markup and CSS floating (which tends to cause many problems like this when used in an attempt at creating tabular appearance), simply put your labels and fields in an HTML table.

Or, if the real case is really as trivial as in the example, simply use some markup that causes line breaks at suitable places (`br`, `div`, or less conveniently `p`) and remove all the odd styling.